# How to make three inline elements have their own alignment?

Tags: css, alignment

In following document I'd like each span to have its own alignment.

```
<h1>
    <span class="left">Left</span>
    <span class="center">Center</span>
    <span class="right">Right</span>
</h1>
```

I can reorder elements and assign styles. I'd like to avoid using block elements if possible.

Desired result:

```
Left             Center            Right|end of container here
```

[So far left span is glued to center](http://jsfiddle.net/e57qb/1/)

**EDIT:**

My left float was always failing due to some stupid programming/layout errors.
Sorry for the stupid question.

[image: works fine now]

Comment: So you were able to get `float:right` done, but not the other direction …?

Comment: Why not `float:left` to first span?

Comment: `.left{float:left;}`? http://jsfiddle.net/e57qb/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs a slight tweaking of your html. But see the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2E3ve/

```
h1 {
    width: 500px;
    background: green;
    text-align: center;
}
.left {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

The main h2 text is center aligned with the left floating left and aligned left and the opposite for the right.

This then fits to the size you set for the h2

Comment: It is. @Austin helped me just fine. I just could not make float:left work.

Answer (score 0):

Float everything to the left.

```
.left, .center, .right {
    float: left;
}
```

And add some padding so they're not touching each other.

```
.center {
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

---

Ideally, however, you should make the container floated to the left. In this case, the container is `h1`, so:

```
h1 {
    float: left;
}
```

---

Here's a fully working jsbin example:
http://jsbin.com/OXolaYi/1/

**page.html**

```
  <div id="#container">
    <h1>
      <span class="left">Left</span>
      <span class="center">Center</span>
      <span class="right">Right</span>
    </h1>
    <div class="theRest">rest of container</div>
  </div>
```

**style.css**

```
h1 {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.center {
    padding: 0 30px;
}
.theRest {
    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="col">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main { text-align: justify; }
.col { display: inline-block; width: 100px; background: red; } 
.spacer { display: inline-block; width: 100%; ]
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6WNGH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

here you go, [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8mCJ/2/)

Html

```
<h1>
    <span class="left">Left</span>
    <span class="center">Center</span>
    <span class="right">Right</span>
</h1>
```

Css

```
.left {position:absolute;
  left:0;top:0;}

.center {
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;}

.right {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;top:0;}
```